# How to access MySQL remotely through workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, windows-server-2008-r2

Hi I'm trying to create a new Connection to an MySQL database installed on a remote Windows server. However, due to server authentication problem, I cannot get the local mysql workbench connected to the remote database. And I could not find a place in workbench where I can provide my server authentication, i.e. username and password to access server. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in the Home window of mysql workbench, near Mysql Connections there is a + button, click on it to Open the setup new Connection wizard, then you get to enter the server's parameters.

```
Hostname : your Windows Server's host name.
Port : Port on which the remote mysql server communicate.
Username : your Mysql server's Username.
Password : your Mysql server's Password.
Default Shcema : the database you want to connect to.
```

Hope this helps